# ASp.NET MVC with Angular 5 project - Add environment config without angular-CLI.json file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular5

I am building a new project in ASP.NET MVC integrated with the **Angular 5** framework with the help of **VS.NET 2017**.

I was following this article https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/ to implement the environment based configuration.

I am new to angular framework. This article is saying to add some environment key-value pairs to the .angular-cli.json file. But my project does not have this file.

Now my doubt is where do i place this below code logic :-

```
{
    "apps":[
        ...
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you created your project using angular-cli? If yes then there should be this file exist

Comment: i created the project within the VS.NET 2017 IDE and did not use the CLI. Instead, i added the required packages inside the package.json file.

Comment: For a suggestion, I could say check this out : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6 .. Especially 2nd and 3rd video of the series. Probably will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using angular-cli. 
Install angular-cli using the following command on the terminal

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Because you are not using angular cli you will have to add several packages and dependencies manually in the package.json file.

Comment: Since i am using the VS.NET and using package.json, why do i need to to use CLI?? . Please suggest , where to write the above code i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Kindly share your folder structure